# Symfony2 Twig template - css not loading

Tags: css, symfony, twig

I have imported the client side of my web app to

> /bundle/Resources/views

This includes html documents, as well as the css, js, images and fonts folders. When i open an html page in a browser, it renders fine. But just by changing the extension of the file to .html.twig and rendering it through the symfony2 framework disables css.

I have also copied the css, js, images and font folders to

> /bundle/Resources/public

I have also tried using the twig assets('') function with no luck.

What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First execute `app/console assets:install` ( consider adding `--symlink` ). The command will copy/symlink all your bundle's `Resources/public` to `web/bundles` and create a folder in there named as the lowercase bundle-name without a trailing "Bundle".

example:

`YourAwesomeBundle\Resources\public\css\style.css` will be copied/symlinked to `web\bundles\yourawesome\css\style.css`

... afterwards include the assets using `asset("@YourBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css")`

... or `asset("bundles/your/css/style.css")`

Comment: Thank you. I just installed Symfony and it was very annoying that the welcome page loaded while all the CSS files that it linked to were empty. Running the app/console assets:install command indeed resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exampe:

**css**

```
{% stylesheets '@TestBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

**js**

```
{% javascripts '@TestBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```